# How to correctly review answers provided to opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, opinion-based

While reviewing Late Answers, I came across an answer to this question: [Can automation QA/Tester work in SDET profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16104662/6186333)

I realized the question, even though it is more than 4 years old and had several up votes, was primarily opinion based and I flagged it as such. However, the late answer (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463253/6186333)) still needed handling. I flagged it as Very Low Quality because it was an opinion provided in response to an opinion based question, but should I have handled it differently?

Comment: well... an answer being primarily opinion based doesn't necessarily make it low quality. It can definitely make it not useful, which we do have a tool for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct reaction is to vote-to-close/flag the question as primarily opinion-based or off-topic (which I just did). You can't blame really a new user for not knowing the rules, and as long as the answer makes sense, I'd leave it alone. You can downvote it if you think it's not useful. Remember that the flag is called *Very* Low Quality, not just Low Quality.

Comment: Should I withdraw my VLQ flag on the answer?

Comment: That seems appropriate. Otherwise you risk your flag being declined.

Comment: Flag withdrawn. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at it is it is the fault of the question, not the answer.  If the question is off topic then it needs to be closed and deleted.

Answers to off topic questions are still answers.  Unless it is gibberish/in a foreign language it is not very low quality.  It is also not not an answer as it answers the question.  This even applies on resource request questions.  Someone giving you the name of a product and link to it on one of those is an answer.

So, in summary, go after the question because once it is deleted it takes the answers with it.

Comment: One begets the other.  The question is the catalyst, but the answer is also a symptom.

Comment: Do we really allow link only answers for resource requests? Shouldn't even an answer to a request to find/recommend a tool explain how said tool solves the problem the OP is having?

Comment: @BSMP Updated the answer.  It needs to be more than just a link but not much more to qualify as an answer.

Comment: While it's true that an answer like this doesn't meet the qualifications for VLQ, it's *not* true that the problems with a question don't affect the quality of an answer, because they do, and it's incorrect to ignore problems with an answer just because the question also has problems (even if they're related).  The answer is a bad answer, and should be treated accordingly (which doesn't mean VLQ, because that's not a flag for bad answers).